# Qt multi-thead console application hangs on exit (using ctrl-c)

Tags: windows, multithreading, qt, threadpool

I'm writing a simple console application that spawns some workers using a QThreadPool.  I'm compiling on Windows 10, using Qt 5.12.2 and Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 14.0 (amd64).  The work needs to start at regular intervals using a timer, but the work takes longer than the interval.  8 threads should be able to keep up with the work load.  I start the application and it works very smoothly and as expected.

When I want to exit the command line application, I hit ctrl-c to stop.  The application then hangs.  The Timer stops and all output stops, but it doesn't return me to the command prompt.  I have to open task manager to quit the application.  I'm sure it has something to do with the QThreadPool not being cleaned up correctly, but I can't find how to clean it up.  Thanks for the suggestions.

I tried catching the destroy signal from the timer and the aboutToQuit signal from the application.  Neither one fire.  If you comment out the start of the thread pool the application quits correctly.  I also created the thread pool as a member variable in the MyTimer class and converted the worker to a pointer.  All variations resulted in the same result, hang on exit.

I don't have a debugger on this machine to attach and see where the application hangs.

mytimer.h

```
#ifndef MYTIMER_H
#define MYTIMER_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QThreadPool>

class MyWorker : public QRunnable
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        QThread::msleep(150);  //simulate some work
        qDebug() << ".";
    }
};

class MyTimer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTimer()
    {
        QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(8);
        worker.setAutoDelete(false);
        // setup signal and slot
        connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(MyTimerSlot()));

        timer.setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer);
        // msec
        timer.start(50);
    }

    QTimer timer;
    MyWorker worker;

public slots:
    void MyTimerSlot()
    {
        //Comment the below line and the ctrl-c will work.
        QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(&worker);
        qDebug() << "-";
    }
};


#endif // MYTIMER_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "mytimer.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyTimer timer;
    return a.exec();
}
```

I expect when I hit ctrl-c while the application is executing, the application will exit cleanly and return control to the command prompt.

Comment: Control handlers execute in a new thread. The default handler calls `ExitProcess`, which terminates all other threads (i.e. all of your application threads) and calls the entry points of loaded DLLs for `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`. This can hang for various reasons. It's also possible that Qt registers a custom control handler (or C `SIGINT` handler) that's hanging.

Comment: Qt needs to seriously improve the robustness of its design if calling `ExitProcess` on a new thread, as is done by the default handler of the console control thread, causes the entrypoint of one or more of its DLLs to hang during `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`. We shouldn't have to override the default control handler just to prevent the app from hanging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. When the application is killed with Ctrl-C it receives a Kill or Abort signal from the Os and it is terminated asap. Therefore no destructors or aboutToQuit signals will be fired as a consequence of the interruption of normal stack unwinding.
2. Your worker class does not handle interruption. Usually a run function has some sort of loop that iterate the work on some chunk of data. In order to stop gracefully the QRunnable you have to exit from the run function. You can do it thread safely using a std::atomic boolean member variable to break the loop into the MyWorker class and using signal/slots to toggle it.

Here is the fix for problem 1:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <csignal>
#include "mytimer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyTimer timer;

    QObject::connect(qApp, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, &timer, &MyTimer::workerStopRequested);

    signal(SIGTERM, [](int sig) { qApp->quit(); });
    signal(SIGABRT, [](int sig) { qApp->quit(); });
    signal(SIGINT, [](int sig) { qApp->quit(); });
    signal(SIGKILL, [](int sig){ qApp->quit(); });

    return a.exec();
}
```

Using the utilities provided in the csignal header file you can catch the killing signal and force the application to quit, firing the aboutToQuit signal.

This signal is also used to tell the MyTimer instance to stop its workers firing the workerStopRequested signal, that is part of the solution to problem 2:

```
#ifndef MYTIMER_H
#define MYTIMER_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QThreadPool>

class MyWorker : public QObject, public QRunnable
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyWorker(QObject* parent = nullptr) :
        QObject(parent),
        QRunnable()
    {
        aborted = false;
    }

    void run()
    {
        while (!aborted)
        {
            QThread::msleep(150);  //simulate some work
            qDebug() << ".";
        }
    }

public slots:
    void abort()
    {
        aborted = true;
        qDebug() << "stopped.";
    }

protected:
    std::atomic<bool> aborted;
};

class MyTimer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTimer()
    {
        QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(8);
        worker.setAutoDelete(false); // <-- Good. Worker is not a simple QRunnable anymore

        // setup signal and slot
        connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(MyTimerSlot()));

        connect(this, &MyTimer::workerStopRequested, &worker, &MyWorker::abort);

        timer.setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer);
        // msec
        timer.start(50);

    }

    QTimer timer;
    MyWorker worker;

signals:
    void workerStopRequested();

public slots:
    void MyTimerSlot()
    {
        //Comment the below line and the ctrl-c will work.
        QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(&worker);
        qDebug() << "-";
    }
};

#endif // MYTIMER_H
```

The MyWorker class inherits from QObject to exploit signal/slots to exit from the run function processing loop. The boolean "aborted" is an atomic variable to guarantee that it is accessed thread-safely. (Atomics are a c++11 feature)

It is set to false after the workerStopRequested signal is emitted (see main.cpp) and the abort() slot is executed, as a consequence of the connection made in the  constructor of MyTimer class.

Notice that when aborted is toggled, it will cause the processing loop to stop at the next iteration. This means that you could see at most 8 dots printed on screen after the "stopped" string (one for each thread according to max thread count).

Comment: There are no POSIX signals in the Windows kernel, so for a Windows-only app there's no point in setting a handler for `SIGTERM` since it only occurs due to an in-process `raise(SIGTERM)`. `SIGKILL` is not defined, and even in POSIX we can't handle it. `SIGABRT` comes from an `abort()` call, so we may want to handle it. For a console application, the C runtime maps `CTRL_C_EVENT` to `SIGINT`, and it maps `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` and `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` to non-standard `SIGBREAK`. For Windows-only code, we can instead set a console control handler directly via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`.

Comment: Thanks! That defiantly worked on being able to catch the SIGINT.  That was the issues I was having.  I think I could have come up with the second half, but I just couldn't figure out how to catch the initial signal that the application had stopped.

The second part doesn't quite fit for "the work" my worker is doing.  It needs to start at regular intervals based on the timer and not run open loop in a while statement.  I'll figure out how to do that, if you have any suggestions on a different thread pattern that would work better, I would appreciate it.  Thanks for getting me over my issue.

Comment: @mushadow Glad it helped :) I think that for your use case, since run does its job and exits, there is no need for the added complexity in the MyWorker class, so you could just stop the timer to prevent the thread pool from spawning new threads.